# Plotting dots with labels and differing colors determined by a row value from csv file in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a csv file in which the first column lists the labels, the second and third lists string and numeric attributes respectively, and the fourth and fifth columns contain the x and y coordinates. I can plot them with

```
plot datafile u 4:5:1 w labels point offset character 0,character 1 tc rgb "blue"
```

However, this only colors the labels and does that so uniformly. I want the labels as well as the dots to be colored differently by the string value of the second column or (in another plot) by the numeric value of the third column.

Comment: How do you want the colors? As RGB values, from a palette, or something else? Please show some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

To specify a numerical color value in column 3 that applies to both text and point color:

```
 plot datafile u 4:5:1:3 with labels point lc variable offset 0,1 tc variable
```

It is not clear what you mean by "colored by the string value".  If the idea is that the second column contains "lavender" or "hot pink" and gnuplot is supposed to interpret that - no, the program isn't that smart.